# How do I query the iPhone's current IP address?

Tags: iphone, networking

How do I query the iPhone's current IP address?

Answer (score 13):

If you want the **external** IP address (the one used to connect from outside the local network), you need to query a server on the external network. A quick search yielded the following: http://checkip.dyndns.org, http://www.whatismyip.com. It is quite simple to load the page using e.g.

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]
```

and do some string manipulation to retrieve the IP address.

If you want the **internal** IP address (the one assigned e.g. by DHCP to your device), what you can usually do is to resolve the device's hostname, i.e.

```
/*
Returns the local IP, or NULL on failure.
*/
const char* GetLocalIP() {
  char buf[256];
  if(gethostname(buf,sizeof(buf)))
    return NULL;
  struct hostent* he = gethostbyname(buf);
  if(!he)
    return NULL;
  for(int i=0; he->h_addr_list[i]; i++) {
    char* ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)he->h_addr_list[i]);
    if(ip != (char*)-1) return ip;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: sometimes my users get null, do you know what's the reason?

Comment: Sorry to bump an old thread, but any chance someone could help me convert this to swift?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use similar to this service:
[Whatismyip](http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp) and capture the string :)

Credit to Erica Sadun's iPhone Developer's Cookbok, 2nd ed, page 555.