# Finding local ip address in the iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I query the iPhone's current IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address)

I'm trying to find the local ip address using gethostname/gethostbyname but I always get "Unable to Resolve" when doing it.

Why could it be failing?
Are there other way to get the local ip address in the iphone?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
    -(NSString*)getAddress {
          char iphone_ip[255];
          strcpy(iphone_ip,"127.0.0.1"); // if everything fails
          NSHost* myhost =[NSHost currentHost];
          if (myhost)
          {
              NSString *ad = [myhost address];
              if (ad)
                  strcpy(iphone_ip,[ad cStringUsingEncoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);
          }

          return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",iphone_ip]; 
     }
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why bother with the C-string at all, as opposed to just using NSString from the beginning?

Comment: i got the code from an online example i found. i'm not sure why they'd use a C-String

Comment: @Andy Jacobs - Could you show us the URL? I'm curious about the why's and how's.

Comment: http://appsamuck.com/day4.html

Comment: this code  NSHost* myhost =[NSHost currentHost]; will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: Same as `NSString *address = [[NSHost currentHost] address]; return (address ? address : @"127.0.0.1");`. As Biranchi said, `NSHost` is a private class.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using gethostname/gethostbyname in the Erica Sadun book.  The trick is to append the ".local" suffix to the hostname before calling gethostbyname.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers here, I would suggest reviewing the Reachability sample code on the ADC site.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that many carriers (especially outside the "first world") hand out RFC1918 (usually 10.0.0.0/8) addresses and so doing a HTTP request to one of the services could be better (except, of course, that many carriers, out of necessity use multiple public addresses for large NAT pools)

Answer (score 0):

NSHost is not found in iPhone OS Library, it is present in Mac OS Core Library.

I am getting 2 warnings

"warning: no '+currentHost' method found"
 "warning: no '-address' method found"

Any way to remove these warnings ???