# How to find ip of iPhone device programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I query the iPhone's current IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address)

How to find ip of iphone device programmatically?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527439/finding-local-ip-address-in-the-iphone