# How can I know the IP address of my iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios-simulator

How can I know the IP address of my iPhone simulator?

Comment: Duplicate question [how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address) it shows how to get Internet address and the local dhcp address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will have the same IP addresses as the computer you’re running it on.

Answer (score 2):

Jep, like Todd said, the same as your machines IP. You can also simply visit http://www.whatismyip.com with mobile Safari or your Mac's web browser ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I think the by visiting the website http://www.test-ipv6.com/ is also a good choice. As the site tells you both the ipv4 and ipv6 global-unicast address

Comment: -1 This site would see the computers IP address, and, because the iPhone Simulator is virtualized, it would only provide the IP address of the host computer and therefore would be of no use to the asker.