# How do I obtain network information in iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I would like to know what the simplest/best way for obtaining information about the current network connection (if any) programmatically in iOS. More specifically:

- Network Connection Type (3G or Wireless)
- Network Operator
- SSID of network
- BSSID of access point
- Mac Address of device
- Current IP address

Comment: There is a wealth of information already available on this topic. Maybe try adding "Reachability" to your searches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone

Comment: as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Network Connection Type:** [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

**MAC Address:** [How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

**IP Address:** [How do I query the iPhone's current IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address)

I'm not sure apple gives you access to the other three things you listed.